# implement generic generic interface in scala

Tags: java, scala

From scala I need to create a java object than it has a method that it demands a parameter that it is a generic interface

java class

```
public class JavaTest<T> {
    public List<T> add(IJavaTest<T> javaTest){
        return null;
    }
}
```

java interface

```
public interface IJavaTest<T> {
    String ss();
}
```

and in scala I implement this:

```
val javaTest = new JavaTest

class TMijavatest[T] extends IJavaTest[T] {
  override def ss(): String = ""
}

val foo=new TMijavatest()
```

But when I call the add method

```
javaTest.add(foo);
```

I have this error in intellij:
Type mismatch, expected:IJavaTest[T], actual TMijavatest[Nothing]

with:

```
javaTest.add(foo.asInstanceOf);
```

It compiles me but in execution time I have this error:

Unexpected error occured in the server.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: my.pakage.Test$TMijavatest$1 cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$

if I generate the foo object just like this:

```
 val foo = new TMijavatest[String]
 javaTest.add(foo);
```

I have this error in intellij:
Type mismatch, expected:IJavaTest[T], actual TMijavatest[String]

How I can do this? Thank you

Comment: Class `TMijavatest` takes a type parameter, but you are instantiating it without a type argument, so `Nothing` is inferred. Specify the type argument. For example: `val foo = new TMijavatest[String]()`

Comment: The same holds true for the `JavaTest` class. It is a generic type, thus you should instantiate it with a type, e.g. `val javaTest = new JavaTest[String]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate JavaTest & TMijavatest with type

```
val javaTest = new JavaTest[String]

class TMijavatest[T] extends IJavaTest[T] {
  override def ss(): String = ""
}

val foo = new TMijavatest[String]

javaTest.add(foo)
```